# Como reiniciar servicios de apache2 en una tares de cron?

Tags: debian, apache2, crontab, sh

Ante todo gracias por su tiempo.
Ví una publicación donde configuran Crontab para que verifique si los servicios de apache están funcionando, y en caso de que no estén funcionando los inicie (o reinicie), la publicación es esta : https://alejandroarco.es/administracion-de-sistemas/linux/como-reiniciar-apache2-debian-con-crontab/

Estaba a ciegas por que para poder ver la salida de la ejecución del archivo .sh ejecutada en crontab había que unas cosas mas y no lo sabia (NO SOY EXPERTO), ahora ya veo la salida y según entiendo esta funcionando pero el comando para reiniciar los servicios de apache requiere interactividad (Ingresar la contraseña), lo googlee pero no conseguí nada, bueno lo que se me ocurrió fue preguntar por aca ojala puedan ayudarme...

este es el código en el script "apache2_restart.sh"

```
set -e

# Variables
NPRO_ACT="$(ps aux | grep apache2 | wc -l)"
NPRO_MIN="1"

echo $NPRO_ACT

# Script
if [ "$NPRO_ACT" -le "$NPRO_MIN" ]; then
sudo service apache2 start

fi

#NPRO_ACT:Número de procesos de apache2 actuales.
#NPRO_MIN:Número de procesos sin iniciar apache2 (comprobar mediante el comando ps aux | grep apache2 | wc -l el número de procesos por defecto).
```

Esta es la salida de la ejecucion del script "apache_restart.sh" en crontab

````
From cacique@cacique-DSK  Tue Oct 25 18:53:01 2022
Return-Path: <cacique@cacique-DSK>
X-Original-To: cacique
Delivered-To: cacique@cacique-DSK
Received: by cacique-DSK (Postfix, from userid 1000)
    id 7D5A0225BD; Tue, 25 Oct 2022 18:53:01 -0400 (-04)
From: root@cacique-DSK (Cron Daemon)
To: cacique@cacique-DSK
Subject: Cron <cacique@cacique-DSK> /scripts/apache2/apache2_restart.sh  
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/home/cacique>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=cacique>
Message-Id: <20221025225301.7D5A0225BD@cacique-DSK>
Date: Tue, 25 Oct 2022 18:53:01 -0400 (-04)


Restarting apache2 (via systemctl): apache2.serviceFailed to restart apache2.service: Interactive authentication required.
See system logs and 'systemctl status apache2.service' for details.
 failed!```


ESTO SOBRE UBUNTU 18.04 EN LOCAL A MODO DE PRUEBA CON EL PROPOSITO DE QUE SI FUNCIONA APLICARLO EN UNA INSTACIA EC2 DE AWS CON DEBIAN 11. (que uso para proyectos personales)

DE ANTE MANO MUCHAS GRACIAS POR EL TIEMPO DEDICADO.
````

Comment: No lo pongas en el cron de tu usuario, sino en el cron de tu root. Seguramente lo encontrarás en el archivo `/var/spool/cron/root` para su edición directa. Y allí ponlo sin sudo.

Comment: ok.. ahorita hago la prueba le hare saber por aqui.. Muchas gracias  (ciertamente agregar sudo fue una de las pruebas que hice q no funciono y no corresponde con la salida q coloque aqui, se me escapo )

Comment: ¿Para verificar que apache esté funcionando? Es mas importante saber por qué ha dejado de funcionar y corregirlo. La solución universal no debe ser reiniciar.

Comment: Si, de hecho me mantengo monitoreando los logs de sistema, aparentemente es la ram cuando llega a sus picos de uso y comienza a usar  mas memoria de intercambio, no es algo q pase seguido, la ultima vez fue hace como dos semanas pero no estaba en mi casa y tarde casi 6 horas el llegar y todo ese tiempo el servidor caído. por eso comencé a hacer pruebas y también a vigilar mas el servidor, pero no doy con la causa. Igual gracias por el consejo, tratare de seguirlo.

Answer (score 0):

Tal y como me comento @masterguru, solo tuve que agregar la tarea al usuario root, fue sencillo solo hacer:

```
sudo su  -> para root

crontab -e ->  para agregar la tarea
```

Con esto ya comenzó a iniciar los servicios de apache sin problema, muchas gracias al usuario `@masterguru`

Comment: No olvides aceptar tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.